# Adding attribution to GeoJSON layer

Tags: python, leaflet, geojson, attribution, ipyleaflet

I'm using `ipyleaflet` and I try to add attribution to a `GeoJSON` layer. I was thinking that `GeoJSON` objects were `TileLayer` so I tried the following:

```py
map = ipyleaflet.Map()

data = json.loads(self.gdf.to_json())
ipygeojson = GeoJSON(data=data, style=AOI_STYLE, name='aoi', attribution='SEPA(c)')

map.add_layer(ipygeojson)
```

But no attributions are set on the map.

lokking at: `help(ipyleaflet.GeoJSON)` I realize that `atttribution` is not a defined or inheritted attribute.

Is there a way to create attribution in `ipyleaflet` for `GeoJSON` objects?

Comment: Vanilla JS Leaflet has [attribution control](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#control-attribution) which allows you to add custom attribution text to the map. There is no such control described in ipyleaflet [docs](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but it seems it was added, see https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/commit/649700d8672abf810411ee9089132298af2ce8ad

Comment: Effectively the AttributionControl exists but it has no methods associated, so it cannot be customized. I opened a issue on their repository: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipyleaflet/issues/847